# MODX установка не работает

Tags: php, modx

Добрвц день. В чем может быть проблема ?
Установил MODX revo фреймвор.
База данных создалась.
Отобразилась страница для входа.
После того как ввожу данные администратора для входа. появляется ошибка 500 и сайт перестаёт вообще загружаться.

Понятно почему так происходит.

```
$modx->initialize('web');
```

Равно null. Не понятно почему.

Лог 1
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @

```
/www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/da9ebb7c9eaba1a42648ec5933d13afb/0/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/index.php
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/da9ebb7c9eaba1a42648ec5933d13afb/1/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/ht.access
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/c8d7691f4f62902521b41c375155963f/0/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/manager/assets
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/c8d7691f4f62902521b41c375155963f/1/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/manager/controllers
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/c8d7691f4f62902521b41c375155963f/2/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/manager/templates
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/c8d7691f4f62902521b41c375155963f/3/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/manager/min
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/c8d7691f4f62902521b41c375155963f/4/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/manager/ht.access
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdoobjectvehicle.class.php : 227) Could not copy /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/modContext/c8d7691f4f62902521b41c375155963f/5/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/manager/index.php
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdofilevehicle.class.php : 40) Could not install files from /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/xPDOFileVehicle/c31025c2565eb475fe8ed40ef647dae7/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/connectors/
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdofilevehicle.class.php : 40) Could not install files from /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/xPDOFileVehicle/73e4e286998fbd67dc6af7e74210dad0/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/connectors/
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdofilevehicle.class.php : 40) Could not install files from /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/xPDOFileVehicle/8d71adbe2039ec8c06a32e816a5153ed/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/connectors/
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/transport/xpdofilevehicle.class.php : 40) Could not install files from /www/dev.modx.ru/core/packages/core/xPDOFileVehicle/e72072ea8e6b00135ac2f27b60058a32/ to /www/dev.modx.ru/connectors/
[2019-04-26 23:07:42] (ERROR @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/model/modx/moduserprofile.class.php : 58) Error HY000 executing statement:
INSERT INTO `modx_user_attributes` (`internalKey`, `fullname`, `email`, `phone`, `mobilephone`, `blocked`, `blockeduntil`, `blockedafter`, `logincount`, `lastlogin`, `thislogin`, `failedlogincount`, `sessionid`, `dob`, `gender`, `address`, `country`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `fax`, `photo`, `comment`, `website`) VALUES (1, 'Администратор по умолчанию', 's.zababurin.v@gmail.com', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1366
    [2] => Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x90\xD0\xB4\xD0\xBC...' for column 'fullname' at row 1
)
```

лог 2

```
[2019-04-26 23:06:17] (ERROR in xPDOConnection::connect @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 3116) SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[2019-04-26 23:06:17] (ERROR in xPDOConnection::connect @ /www/dev.modx.ru/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 3116) SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Може быть кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой ?

Comment: Прежде всего загляните пожалуйста в лог /core/cache/logs/, и в консоль веб-разработчика,не должно быть никаких ошибок, иначе в студию их!
Также интересно будет услышать параметры вашего серверного окружения, версию устанавливаемого MODX.

Comment: Первый лог - причина в неверно установленной кодировке  у базы - она не utf8. Второй лог - попытка соединения с базой с пустым логином и без пароля